# In what language are OS programmed

Tags: operating-system, openbsd

This question may sound stupid but i couldn't find a real answer so here it is:

In what programming language are OSs programmed?
In what language is OpenBSD programmed?
Can you programm and operating in every scripting language (Ruby, Python,...etc)?

Comment: You need at least C/C++ but that is not all you need, there is way more things you need to learn before you make OS! Scripting languages  run in interpreters they can't be compiled in real byte code, they have different purpose

Comment: OpenBSD is open source, so you can look in the CVS repo to find out what various parts are written in.

Answer (score 3):

Most operating systems are programmed in C. Some parts of some operating systems may use C++ or Objective C as well. Also, operating systems must have some assembly in them.

Although you can theoretically program parts of an OS in a scripting language, it would not be so easy. At least some of the OS would need to be compiled to native code. However, the operating system might have a built in interpreter for a scripting language or virtual machine for bytecode. Then you could write, for example, device drivers in the scripting language, where the driver presents a certain interface to the OS. You could also maybe write scheduling policies, paging systems, etc. in the scripting language. Basically your scripting language would provide a nice way to quickly prototype and test new modules and OS concepts. However, I wouldn't recommend such a system for production environment because you usually take a performance hit with the types of languages that you mention.

I am not aware of any operating system that uses anything like this. I am vaguely aware that some research OSes have been developed that used similar ideas, though I can't name any off the top of my head.

Comment: Also [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) can act as a primitive OS itself.